# Suggestions to improve my layout

Tags: android, xml

I would like to improve the design of my home page for my app but I don't know how to and I don't really have good designing skills,could someone please give me some suggestions.Thank you.

[image]

This is my code for this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#fff59d"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ie.example.artur.projectrepeat.Main2Activity">




    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/sample"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View All"
        android:id="@+id/view_all"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_add" />




    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/sample"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_Number"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText_Number" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Quantity"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_amount"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Category"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_Product"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Quantity"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <!--<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_id"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_id"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Category"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />-->

    <EditText
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:hint="@string/Enter_Name"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText_Category"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText_Quantity"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText_Quantity"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button_add"

        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sample"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Please Choose your Product"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText_name" />

    <EditText
        android:hint="Importance of product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Category"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText_Category"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText_Category" />
    <![CDATA[

    SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_add" />


]]>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post a screenshot please

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is subject to be highly opinionated (UI design advice: completely off-topic). One golden rule is: `less is more`. In particular, referred to all those eye-hurting colors you used.

Comment: This android related ,design is a part of android how could it be off-topic .Where else I'm supposed to get suggestions about android if not on this website???

Comment: This site is code-specific issues, not for nice UI design (which is **not** related to any specific OS by any means).

Comment: I have seen many question which are not code-specific answered many times ,it seems to me you just do what ever you want on this site because you are one of the admins.And how can this not be code-specific if you need code to make a good design?What you are saying does not make sense.

Comment: A better fit would be here: http://ux.stackexchange.com   However, this would still be too broad.  Narrow your question down to a specific issue.

Comment: `it seems to me you just do what ever you want on this site` No, you **can't**. `you are one of the admins` No, I am **not**. `you need code to make a good design?` No, you actually **don't** - you only need some xml. Most of the times done in the graphical editor, so you could (stressed: COULD) even not see a single line of xml in your career. Some knowledge of Gimp and/or Inkscape would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please choose your product   "
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/MyButtonStack"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_send_white_24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75px"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText">
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginRight="15px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter product name"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText">
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginRight="15px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter quantity"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50px"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText">

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginRight="15px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter product category"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50px"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText4" />
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintText">

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginRight="15px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter product importance"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText5" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/MyButtonStack"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText5" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View all"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/MyButtonStack"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1" />
```

**styles**

```
<style name="MyButtonStack" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/active</item>
</style>
<!--Floating label text style-->
<style name="MyHintText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/active</item>
</style>

<!--Input field style-->
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

you can go further by replacing the category field with a spinner and the quantity with a slider/number picker
I would recommend using google's material design, for buttons and what not
these websites will guide through designing a fresh and modern User Interface [Material design docs](http://www.materialdoc.com/components/), [Google's material design documentations](https://material.google.com/#) and for the icons [Material design icons](https://design.google.com/icons/)